# how to force invalidate()?

Tags: java, android, image-processing, bitmap

i've got the following classes that make up my app that places a fisheye distortion on a bitmap. when i load the bitmap it ONLY displays when i touch the screen or slidebar and doesn't display the bitmap after the view's constructor has completed. i've put some logging in there and basically the ondraw() is called but nothing is drawn to the canvas. How can i get the app to invalidate straight after the view constructor completes?

```
public class TouchView extends View{

    private File tempFile;
    private byte[] imageArray;
    private Bitmap bgr;
    private Bitmap bm;
    private Bitmap bgr2 = null;;
    private Paint pTouch;
    private float centreX = 1;
    private float centreY = 1;
    private int radius = 50;
    private int Progress = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "*********TouchView";
    private Filters f = null;
    private boolean AsyncRunning = false;
   // private MyTask mt = null;



    public TouchView(Context context) {
        super(context);
       // TouchView(context, null);
    }




    public TouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context,attr);
        Log.e(TAG, "++++++++++ inside touchview constructor");



        tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
                getAbsolutePath() + "/"+"image.jpg");

        imageArray = new byte[(int)tempFile.length()];


     try{

            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);


            int i = 0;

            while (dis.available() > 0) {
            imageArray[i] = dis.readByte();
            i++;
            }

            dis.close();

       } catch (Exception e) {

               e.printStackTrace();
            }



        BitmapFactory.Options bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bfo.inSampleSize = 1;

        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageArray, 0, imageArray.length, bfo);


        bgr = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), bm.getConfig());
        bgr = bm.copy(bm.getConfig(), true);
        bgr2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), bm.getConfig());



        f = new Filters();


        pTouch = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);         
        pTouch.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_OUT)); 
        pTouch.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        pTouch.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        Log.e(TAG, "++++++++++ end od touchview constructor");
    }// end of touchView constructor


    public void findCirclePixels(){ 

        Log.e(TAG, "++++++++++ inside fpc");
              new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    float prog = (float)Progress/150000;

                final Bitmap bgr3 = f.barrel(bgr,prog,centreX,centreY);
                  TouchView.this.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                      TouchView.this.bgr2 = bgr3;
                      TouchView.this.invalidate();
                    }
                  });
                }
              }).start();


        /*
        float prog = (float)Progress/150000;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        bgr2 = f.barrel(bgr,prog);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long duration = endTime - startTime;
        Log.e(TAG, "++++++++++ barrel() took "+ duration+" ms");
        */

              Log.e(TAG, "++++++++++ end fpc");
        }// end of changePixel()




    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        switch (ev.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                centreX = (int) ev.getX();
                centreY = (int) ev.getY();
                //findCirclePixels();
                TouchView.this.invalidate();

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

                    centreX = (int) ev.getX();
                    centreY = (int) ev.getY();
                  //  findCirclePixels();
                  TouchView.this.invalidate();
                    break;

            }           

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 

                break;

        }
        return true;
    }//end of onTouchEvent





    public void initSlider(final HorizontalSlider slider)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "******setting up slider*********** ");
        slider.setOnProgressChangeListener(changeListener);

    }



    private OnProgressChangeListener changeListener = new OnProgressChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(View v, int progress) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


              setProgress(progress);
            //TouchView.this.Progress = progress;


        }
    };




    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Log.e(TAG, "++++++++++ inside ondraw");
        canvas.drawBitmap(bgr2, 0, 0, null);
       // canvas.drawCircle(centreX, centreY, radius,pTouch);

        Log.e(TAG, "++++++++++end ondraw");

    }//end of onDraw




    protected void setProgress(int progress2) {
        Log.e(TAG, "***********in SETPROGRESS");
        this.Progress = progress2;



        findCirclePixels();
        invalidate();


    }




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitmap bgr2 is created in constructor but **nothing** is painted in it. It will get painted from findCirclePixels which gets called on slider change.

I think `createBitmap (int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config)` only uses config, you can use other variant create bitmap may be

```
Bitmap createBitmap (Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

Comment: hi ah yes silly overlook. I've got the canvas to draw bgr bitmap now but it still doesn't draw it until i touch the slider. i've tried calling invalidate after the bgr bitmap is created. not sure where the best place is to call invalidate

Comment: After creating and adding view in activity you can send invalidate directly or call a method to invalidate?

Comment: mmm i've tried calling invalidate after setting up the slider in activity but it still doesn't display bgr bitmap after view is inflated

Comment: There are two constructors which one you are using..? one which takes only context will not create resources

Comment: it's ok it works now. bgr2 is an empty bitmap until findcirclepixels is invoked. so i deleted bgr2, painted bgr and set bgr = bgr3 in fcp(). thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Calling invalidate() in onAttachedToWindow() maybe?